# I can not connect the widget to the database fiware

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I need to connect a widget to a database on my machine with Orion OS. The problem is that when I connect to a machine where I have fixed data if I connected. But when I connect it to my machine, with data that is automatically updated, it does not work and doesn't display data on the map.

Has the same configuration in the cloud.

Do I have to take any preliminary step in the putty to extract the data from the widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please be more specific with your problem by providing a concrete example. I'm barely able to understand it right now.

Anyway... it is possible that Orion callbacks aren't able to reach your local machine, it is your IP public or conveniently exposed via NAT?